# WPF - Default Resources Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to add ImageControl in XAML using code below :

`<Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding driveType, 
 Converter=   {StaticResource imageConverter}}" />`

and the only problem is that when converter return path like :
`./mySampleImageSource.png`

the image couldnt be found because default `.\` refers to `P:\VisualStudio2015\Common7\IDE\`

it works only when I return fullpath to the folder where the file is but of course it is very impractical solution.

So my question is if there is a way to change this default `.\` path?

Comment: [Pack Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the directory that your current app is running in, then use this variable `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. Then you can use `Path.Combine` to build a path to where you are storing your image files